# Google Maps API/Geocoding - Can I retrieve a response by just passing a ZIP code?

Tags: .net, google-maps

Greetings:

I have put together a RESTful web service in .NET 3.5 that takes a phone number and does a reverse lookup to retrieve the ZIP code of that location. I am now creating an *.aspx page that will present the output of a request to the Google Maps API. This output will be a polygon on a map that will be that US ZIP code. I'm wondering if I could just pass in only that ZIP code in the http request for the address parameter. The example at http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/ basically passes in the entire street address. Not quite sure if the ZIP would be sufficient.

Anyone had experience working with this?

Thanks in advance!

Todd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing in just the zip code should work fine.

Making a request to [http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?**q=63131**&output=json&oe=utf8&sensor=false](http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=63131&output=json&oe=utf8&sensor=false) gives you a valid result with a LatLonBox in the ExtendedData property.  You'll have to manually go to that URL, since Google refuses requests without an API key if they have a referring URL.

Comment: I also made note that yahoo has a similar RESTful geocoding service. I appreciate it again!

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that I used that I only passed a postal code to and it works fine.

```
var map = null;
  var geocoder = null;
  var address = "SW1A 0AA";

  function initialize() {
    if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
      map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
      map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
      map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
      map.setMapType(G_HYBRID_MAP);
      geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();

        if (geocoder) {
            geocoder.getLatLng(
              address,
              function(point) {
                  map.setCenter(point, 13);
                  var marker = new GMarker(point);
                  map.addOverlay(marker);
              }
            );
          }
    }
  }
```